# How do I create a new JavaScript array without destroying the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I never seem to understand JavaScript fully. Please explain this to me.

I have an array of objects called arr1. In this simplified example, it has only two members; name and someValue. The array is sorted by name and the content looks like this:

```
Harry   1
Joe     2
Joe     3
Peter   4
```

I want to create another array called arr2. It should hold the unique names from arr1. If a duplicate is found, the someValue is added for that name. I basically want this as content in arr2:

```
Harry   1
Joe     5 <-- the two values from Joe in arr1 sums up to 5
Peter   4
```

So I came up with the script below. The resulting arr2 is exactly what I want. 
However, the arr1 is also updated and that's not what I desire.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];

arr1.push({name: 'Harry', someValue: 1});
arr1.push({name: 'Joe', someValue: 2});
arr1.push({name: 'Joe', someValue: 3});
arr1.push({name: 'Peter', someValue: 4});

let previousName = '';

for (var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
  if (arr1[i].name == previousName) {
    arr2[arr2.length-1].someValue += arr1[i].someValue;
  } else {
    arr2.push(arr1[i]);
    previousName = arr1[i].name;
  }
}

/* Result arr1 is not ok:
0: Object { name: "Harry", someValue: 1 }
1: Object { name: "Joe", someValue: 5 } <-- I want the value 2 to be preserved
2: Object { name: "Joe", someValue: 3 }
3: Object { name: "Peter", someValue: 4 }

   Result arr2 is ok:
0: Object { name: "Harry", someValue: 1 }
1: Object { name: "Joe", someValue: 5 }
2: Object { name: "Peter", someValue: 4 }
*/
```

Comment: `arr2.push(arr1[i])` Both the object from the first and the second have the same reference

Comment: This happens because the array elements are not primitives, hence they are kind of passed by "reference" (though it's not exactly a reference). You need to **deep copy** the values first, otherwise altering either of them will effectively update both.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are pushing the *object instance* from `arr1` onto `arr2`, instead of a copy.

Instead, simply create a new instance of the object when pushing onto `arr2` and you will correct the problem.

Replace this line (which pushes the *instance* from `arr1` onto `arr2`:

```
arr2.push(arr1[i]);
```

With this line (which creates a new *instance* and pushes it onto `arr2`:

```
arr2.push({name: arr1[i].name, someValue: arr1[i].someValue});
```

Here's a working snippet showing this:

```js
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];

arr1.push({name: 'Harry', someValue: 1});
arr1.push({name: 'Joe', someValue: 2});
arr1.push({name: 'Joe', someValue: 3});
arr1.push({name: 'Peter', someValue: 4});
;
let previousName = '';

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if (arr1[i].name == previousName) {
    arr2[arr2.length - 1].someValue += arr1[i].someValue;
  } else {
    arr2.push({name: arr1[i].name, someValue: arr1[i].someValue});
    previousName = arr1[i].name;
  }
}

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 3):

It happens because arrays and objects are reference types.  So when you are editing 
a reference , then it means that all objects will be edited.

So try to use spread operator to create brand new object:

```
arr2.push({...arr1[i]});
```

or `Object.assign`:

```
arr2.push(Object.assign({}, arr1[i]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Thing is when you modify those values, as they are references, mean that they are connected, they are pointing to the same memory location where it keeps the value. Creating a duplicate, but separate array `a2` such that changing `a1[k]` will not cause `a2[k]` to match the modified `a1[k]` requires **cloning**.

Shallow copies can be done using a simple loop or slicing. `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` creates deep copies.

This link will explain you deeper why and how to solve it.
[How to clone an array in JavaScript](http://How%20to%20clone%20an%20array%20in%20JavaScript)